# JPA - join fetch on a field using Root, Join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

I have these classes, fields are lazy loaded always.

```
public class Book {
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private Publication publication;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<Author> authors;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<Genre> genres;
}

public class Publication{
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<Founder> founders;

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is join fetching on a join fetch.  In hql, it looks like this:

```
FROM Book b LEFT JOIN b.authors LEFT JOIN b.genres LEFT JOIN b.publication p LEFT JOIN p.founders
```

This is what I've tried so far but it is not working:

```
Root<Book> root ...
Join<Book, Publication> publication = root.join("publication");
publication.fetch("founders");
root.fetch("authors");
root.fetch("genres");
```

Here's the cause of the exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:588)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specification of JPA says:

> Multiple levels of fetch joins are not required to be supported by an
>   implementation of this specification. Applications that use
>   multi-level fetch joins will not be portable.

Try to reduce fetch joins from the query and initialize data later (after data select).
You can initialize lazy loaded data using size() or Hibernate.initialize() in the same transaction e.g.:

```
publication.getFounders().size();
```

or

```
Hibernate.initialize(publication.getFounders());
```

Comment: I ended up doing your suggestion.  Thanks!